# GWT table add entry row

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I'm new to GWT and am trying to create a table to display my data in. I started using a datagrid (as I wanted hierarchical headers as in the datagrid showcase example). My other requirement is that the top row be a dedicated "add entry row", i.e. it is empty row where the cells hold input boxes that can be completed by the user, and the last column contains an "Add" button to add the completed item to the data set. All other data is in the table is non editable and once the "Add" row button is clicked, the contents of the "add entry row" are written to the permanent table contents a the "add entry row" is cleared.

As I'm new to GWT I thought I'd check if there is an easy way to achieve this functionality? Or can anyone offer advice as to how best implement this?

Comment: Go through the following link. http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After You click on `ADD` button .

Create `YourObject` with those values and ,Then you can add one record to the `listdata`

which is populating your `DataGrid.`

By using  below code you can acheive that :

```
//TO DO  create `yourObject` here with new values 
ListDataProvider.getList.Add(yourObject);
ListDataProvider.refresh();
```

Comment: There is no need to redraw DataGrid. It's enough to call `refresh()` on DataProvider.

Comment: When the underlying data is refreshed the entire Grid is redrawn.@Andrie is'nt it ??

Comment: Actually, it's enough to simply add a new object to DataProvider. No need to call redraw() or refresh().

Comment: No need to call DataGrid.reDraw(). When you call redraw the entire Grid including columns, headers, and body is redrawned. In the above mentioned case you no need to redraw the columns and headers. You just need to refresh the body. So, ListDataProvider.refresh is sufficient. And refresh is mandatory to make changes reflect in the UI.